# Why am I getting this "undefined method split" error?

Tags: ruby, csv

I want to split the original file by 2 delimiters, comma and colon, and then store the split file separately. My program is this:

```
require 'csv'

CSV.open('SplitFile.csv', "wb") do |csv|
    CSV.foreach('Original.csv') do |row|
        csv<<row.split(/[,:]/)
    end
end
```

But I get this error: `undefined method 'split' for #<Array:0x363d0e0> (NoMethodError)`. Why is that?

EDIT: I got it to work using the following:

```
require 'csv'
CSV.open('SplitFile.csv', "wb") do |csv|
    f = File.open('Original.csv', "r")
    f.each_line { |line|
    row = line.split(/[,:]/)
    csv << row
}
end
```

Thanks to the answerers. Their methods work too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split it's method for `String's`

You can try something like `row.map{|s|s.split(/[,:]/)}`

Answer (score 0):

Because `row` is an Array, not a String.

For example:

```
cat mycsv.csv
row,of,CSV,data
row,of,CSV,data
row,of,CSV,data
row,of,CSV,data

CSV.foreach('mycsv.csv') do |row|
  puts row.inspect
end
=> 
["row", "of", "CSV", "data"]
["row", "of", "CSV", "data"]
["row", "of", "CSV", "data"]
["row", "of", "CSV", "data"]
```

I don't know what is the contents of `Original.csv` file, but I think you can do like this:

```
row.first.split(/[,:]/)
```